# Cannot delete foreign key restraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When i try to delete my user object its gets stopped due to a foreign key restraint... i understand why this is because of the relationship in the model so i added `dependent: :destroy` to cater for this but its still not working

This is my user model:

```
    class User < ApplicationRecord
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable,
             :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :omniauthable, omniauth_providers:[:twitter]
      acts_as_voter
      enum role: [:user, :admin]
      validates :username, presence: true,
                          length: { minimum: 4, maximum: 16}
      has_many :entries, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :reports, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
      has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :winners, dependent: :destroy

      def self.from_omniauth(auth)
        where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
          user.provider = auth.provider
          user.uid      = auth.uid
          user.username = auth.info.name
          user.email = auth.info.email
          user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
          if user.save
            Profile.create_new_profile(user.id)
          end
        end
```

and my profile model

```
    class Profile < ApplicationRecord
      mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
      belongs_to :user
      delegate :username, to: :user, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
      delegate :score, to: :user, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
```

any ideas?

The error:

```
SQL (1.0ms) DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 [["id", 56]] (0.1ms) ROLLBACK ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: update or delete on table "users" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_e424190865" on table "profiles" DETAIL: Key (id)=(56) is still referenced from table "profiles". : DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1
```

Comment: Can we see the error ?

Comment: SQL (1.0ms)  DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  [["id", 56]]
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "users" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_e424190865" on table "profiles"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(56) is still referenced from table "profiles".
: DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1

Comment: Are you using delete or destroy to remove the objects?

Comment: @snake Im using destroy

Comment: @snake delete also raises the same error

Comment: Have you restarted the server and/or the rails console?

Comment: Is it possible (by mistake), that a user has more than one profile?. Has_one would only delete one (I think). Can you query the database `select profiles.* where user_id = XXX` (the user)

Comment: @Pablo, This was indeed the case! Im not quite sure how it happened though? I thought the has_one wouldnt allow this or am i wrong? Can you please answer the question so i can mark it answered please. Thankyou

Comment: The has_one cannot control what you do in the database. You could have added the profile with an insert. I added the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible (by mistake), that a user has more than one profile.
**Has_one** would only delete one.

You should query the database to check:

```
select profiles.* where user_id = XXX (the user)
```

Note: If a user can have more than one profile, you should use `has_many`. In this case the destroy will destroy all profiles.